# LSTM between Conv Layers?

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

In my 3D segmentation problem I would like to train sequences of (variable length) 2d Images to produce a semantic segmentation with the same input size.

My current model is a u-net. The results are ok processing each 2d image independently.

To modelize the sequence I would like to include a lstm in the bottom part of the u-net (where has less features).

So I'm aware that I should use timestep = 1 , stateful= True, return_sequences = True

But I really don't know how to put the lstm between conv layers...